# FRW Metric maximally symmetric, derivation, $R=3K$ or $R=6K$ confusion, two different texts

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, metric-tensor, curvature, conventions

I'm looking at Tod and Hughston Introduction to GR and writing the metric in the two forms;

[1]$$
ds^{2}=dt^{2}-R^{2}(t)(\frac{dr^{2}}{1-kr^{2}}+r^{2}(d\theta^{2}+sin^{2}\theta d\phi^{2}))
$$
[2] $$
ds^{2}=dt^{2}-R^{2}(t)g_{ij}dx^{i}dx^{j}
$$
where 
$$
g_{ij}dx^{i}dx^{j}=d\chi^{2}+\chi^{2}(d\theta^{2}+sin^{2}\theta d\phi^{2}) 
$$ 
for k=0
$$
=d\chi^{2}+sin^{2}\chi{2}(d\theta^{2}+sin^{2}\theta d\phi^{2})$$
for k=1
$$
=d\chi^{2}+sinh^{2}\chi{2}(d\theta^{2}+sin^{2}\theta d\phi^{2})$$
for k=-1

Now in solving for the form [2] it computes the Ricci scalar of 
$$
ds^{2}=d\chi^{2}+f^{2}(\chi)(d\theta^{2}+sin^{2}\theta d\phi^{2}
$$
and finds 
$$
R=-(2\frac{f''}{f}-\frac{1}{f^{2}}+\frac{(f')^{2}}{f^{2}}
$$
then integrates, uses 
$$R=3k$$
and solves for all 3 cases 
$$k=0,\pm 1$$.

My Question:

$$R=3k$$
doesn't seem right to me, since in 3-d space 
$$
R_{ab}=2kg_{ab}. 
$$

Of course you could just define a constant 
$$
K=2k
$$,

but it uses the constant $$k$$ in the FRW metric of the form [1], comparing to Introduction to GR lecture notes by sean M.Caroll 1997,I thought that this should be $$R=6k$$..

In Caroll's notes he uses $$R_{ab}=2kg_{ab}$$ in the derivation and gives the FRW metric  the same as in form [1]. So it doesn't look as though Tod has used $$K=2k$$.
Can anyone help explain how Tod uses $$R=3k$$?

Thanks.